# Convert RFC 822 Date to TDateTime

Tags: delphi, datetime, rfc822

Can anyone suggest a Delphi library that will covert a date string in the RFC 822 format to a TDateTime?

e.g. 24 Oct 2011 13:54:55 -0000

I imagine this is something that you could easily get wrong due to slight variations in formats returned by servers, so a tried and tested routine would be good.

Can this be achieved with the built in StrToDateTime routine using a custom short date format sting?

Note: I'm using Delphi 2010

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Indy's [`TIdDateTimeStamp`](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/007276.html) (since Indy 9) has [`SetFromRFC822`](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/007276.html#0046) method which calls [`StrInternetToDateTime`](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/007117.html).

Comment: Since Indy 10 [StrInternetToDateTime](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy10/StrInternetToDateTime@string.html) is located in the IdGlobalProtocols unit